# Why is my program not running? Please check

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

The following program prompts the user to enter a word; reverse the word and print it. I believe my program contains no error but it does not seem to run in eclipse. Please somebody check my code. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reverseWord 
{

public static String reverse(String m)
{
String reverse = "";
int Length = m.length();
for(int i = Length-1; i>=0; i=i-1)
{
    reverse = reverse +  m.charAt(i);
}
return reverse;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String store = keyIn.nextLine();
    reverseWord rw = new reverseWord();
    rw.reverse(store);

}
}
```

Comment: the only thing I see is that "length" is probably not a safe name for a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only returning the reversed String but no printing it out to the console. You should also changed the method to be a non-static method or accessing it using the class name instead of an instance. And class names in java always start with a uppercase letter :) Try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseWord {

    public String reverse(String m) {
        String reverse = "";
        int Length = m.length();
        for (int i = Length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
            reverse = reverse + m.charAt(i);
        }
        return reverse;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String store = keyIn.nextLine();
        ReverseWord rw = new ReverseWord();
        String reversedWord = rw.reverse(store);
        System.out.println(reversedWord);

    }
}
```

Comment: But still it is not running, I do not know why.

Comment: @socrates It works perfectly on my machine... Have you also renamed the java file to start with a uppercase letter?

Comment: At the bottom right side, I see "check server availability" whenever I run the code.

Comment: @socrates I don't know what IDE you're using but that should not be a problem with your code.

Comment: I tried running in both eclipse and netbeans, but it does not run.

Comment: However, other programs are running perfectly.

Comment: @socrates Thats strange... but it must be a problem with your setup or IDE. I've now tried to compile and run it in a command line and everything works fine. In eclipse you can try and right click on the file and select "run as" > "Java Application" so you can be sure you are executing the right file.

Comment: @socrates Please accept the answer since there should be no problem with the code. If you still get errors you can ask a new question specifically for the IDE you are using .